# Access localStorage before page rendering in nextjs

Tags: next.js

I want user will not redirect to login page on closing website or browser once user is loggedIn.for this i use localStorage. it is working successfully but, it works after page rendering in nextjs. so, it give me error for 5 seconds. i want to access localStorage before page rendering in nextjs.[![First image shown when website is launch[image: Then the routes automatically changes after 5 secondsThis is my code for accessing localStorage and setting conditions]

Answer (score 2):

Local Storage is only available in the browser. It will not be available on the server (or while the page is doing any kind of server-side operation).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

You should use a cookie to store this information if it needs to be accessible by both the server AND client.

Comment: but it will remove after closing browser

Comment: @abhijain Cookies also persist through closing the browser.